# assembly 6502 printing numbers in the console

Tags: assembly, printing, console, 6502

let say we have adress:

```
2000: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00...
```

and after some we exececuted some instructions in assembly we got

`2000: 30 31 30 31 30 31 31 31 00`    `;this are ASCII '0' and '1' number representation.`

So I would like to print this 01010111 in my PC console. What is the best way and how to do it?
Is the addres where we store this numbers important or it doesnt matter? I am using Xasm compiler and emu6502 to run .obx. I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: Doesn't emu6502 come with any documentation? Start by looking up how to write characters to the console.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that emu6502 has an "output" display.  It only has a memory array and the processor code.  You will have to add code to display the ascii coded bytes in the emulator's memory to a textbox on a windows form or to a console.